# Is it possible to have django apps in their own docker container and manage/interact with them?

Tags: django, docker, containers

Is it possible to have each app in a django project in its own docker container? this way

1- All the dependencies of the app is contained to itself and there wont be any dependency conflicts between two apps.

2- In our project we are discussing a use case where  apps should deployed in  containers(primary and backup) such that when the primary goes down the backup takes over .. basically implementing High availability(HA) of an app.

I know that this may not exactly be a use case that Django was built to solve, but if it is doable in Django then i would like to do it using django as we have already created lot of apps using django and changing the architecture for the sake of HA would be a lot of work.

Note: I understand that the whole project can be deployed in a container and HA can be implemented.. but i'm more interested distributing apps in containers.

Comment: Is this multiple independant django apps? Or is this a single monolith that needs to be split into multiple docker containers?

Comment: @Pandelis These are multiple independent  django apps that are part of the same django project.